# code from a string to html

Tags: php, html, twig

I currently am writing code for a post system. The posts are written to a file and I read back from the file to show them to the visitor.

The php is fine and reads everything from the file.

```
implode('', file(__DIR__ .'../docs/posts/'. next($right)  . '.txt')
```

Afterwards i want to show the code i read from the file into my twig template

```
<article class="newsposttext">{{ nptext }}</article>
```

This also shows the text where i want it and in the right style, although the code is shown with the tags and the tags aren't "processed" by html and shown as i without tags and as text/images/links...

```
<p>some text</p>
```

when i use developer toolbar:

```
<article>"<p>some tex</p>"<article>
```

my question is: how can i remove those " at the beginning and end or should i do it in another way?

Comment: By using pure php you could do as simple as: <article><?= $content ?></article>

Comment: You're using a templating system or something?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added that tag to the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try:**

```
{{ nptext|raw }}
```

**Documentation:**
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$nptext = '"<p>some text</p>"'; // output: "<p>some text</p>" 

$nptext = str_replace('"', '', $nptext); // output: <p>some text</p>
```

Comment: i don't have to replace all the '"' since image tags for example would forget the src="logo.png" in that case

Comment: just tried
    rtrim(ltrim(implode('', file(__DIR__ .'../docs/posts/'. next($right)  . '.txt')), '"'), '"')
but it didn't work either